# Upgrading from 2.2.0 -> 2.3.2: Type 'unknown' does not satisfy the constraint 'Record<never, never>'

Tags: hilla

I am using Hilla for my project because I need a Java backend so that I can use auto-generated java library code. The library code is in another jar on the classpath.
The issue I am seeing is related to the changes in this PR:
https://github.com/vaadin/hilla/pull/1252

The code below worked ok with Hilla 2.2.0.

I have a library interface:

```
public interface HlaTimeStamped<T> {
   T getValue();
   HlaTimeStamp getTimeStamp();
   HlaLogicalTime getLogicalTime();
}
```

The relevant generated frontend ts is:

```
/* HlaTimeStamped.ts */
import type HlaLogicalTime_1 from "./HlaLogicalTime.js";
import type HlaTimeStamp_1 from "./HlaTimeStamp.js";
interface HlaTimeStamped {
    value: unknown;
    timeStamp?: HlaTimeStamp_1;
    logicalTime?: HlaLogicalTime_1;
}
export default HlaTimeStamped;
```

and

```
/* HlaTimeStampedModel.ts */
class HlaTimeStampedModel<T extends HlaTimeStamped_1 = HlaTimeStamped_1> extends ObjectModel_1<T> {
    static override createEmptyValue = makeObjectEmptyValueCreator_1(HlaTimeStampedModel);
    get value(): ObjectModel_1<unknown> { /* Type 'unknown' does not satisfy the constraint 'Record<never, never>'. */
        return this[_getPropertyModel_1]("value", (parent, key) => new ObjectModel_1(parent, key, false));
    }
    get timeStamp(): HlaTimeStampModel_1 {
        return this[_getPropertyModel_1]("timeStamp", (parent, key) => new HlaTimeStampModel_1(parent, key, true));
    }
    get logicalTime(): HlaLogicalTimeModel_1 {
        return this[_getPropertyModel_1]("logicalTime", (parent, key) => new HlaLogicalTimeModel_1(parent, key, true));
    }
}
```

When the application is built I get the error
`Type 'unknown' does not satisfy the constraint 'Record<never, never>'.` from the value() function declaration.

The issue is that previously, `ObjectModel` is declared as

```
export declare class ObjectModel<T> extends AbstractModel<T>
```

whereas now it is

```
declare class ObjectModel<T extends Record<never, never> = Record<never, never>> extends AbstractModel<T> { ... }
```

I am stumped as how to fix this, given that all the code here is autogenerated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is clearly a bug in Hilla and not with your library code. I submitted this as an issue here: https://github.com/vaadin/hilla/issues/1612

Unfortunately, generic parameters are not supported as such yet. Emitting something like `unknown` in TypeScript for such cases is probably the best we could offer at the moment. However, it is not expected that Hilla generates erroneous TypeScript models for this missing feature.

As a workaround, please try applying an upper bound to the generic parameter:

```
public interface HlaTimeStamped<T extends Entity> {
    T getValue();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for raising the issue. I'll have to hold on for a fix to this as there is no suitable upper bound on T.